# Angularjs2 show json like tree

Tags: json, angular, tree

I create a json file like

> { "tests": { "CHE": { "Failover": [ "Standalone Box Restart" ],
>   "Smoke": [ "All Domains Are Published", "No FID Duplication", "PE and
>   RIC Mangling", "Real Time Updates - FTN", "Only One Response Message
>   Per Constituent", "LIVE-STANDBY-LIVE Switch" ] }, "Queries": {
>   "Queries": [ "Get Services For Region" ] } } }

How to show on the HTML like a tree really hurry up. Thank you
Like That:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojrhi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this way.

First of all you need to create pipe using `ng generate pipe testPipe` (this will also import the dependency in `app.module.ts` file) for converting the object to array for looping through the elements.

**test-pipe.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keys'
})
export class TestPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

 transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }

}
```

In your template file place below mentioned code.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data | keys">
    <ul>
      <li>
        {{item.key}}
         <ul *ngFor="let inItem of item.value | keys">
           <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="">{{inItem.key}}
             <ul *ngFor="let ininItem of inItem.value | keys">
               <li>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="">{{ininItem.key}}
                 <ul *ngFor="let inininItem of ininItem.value | keys">
                   <li>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="">{{inininItem.value}}
                   </li>
                 </ul>
               </li>
             </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

in your component file you can right like.

```
data = { "tests": { "CHE": { "Failover": [ "Standalone Box Restart" ], "Smoke": [ "All Domains Are Published", "No FID Duplication", "PE and RIC Mangling", "Real Time Updates - FTN", "Only One Response Message Per Constituent", "LIVE-STANDBY-LIVE Switch" ] }, "Queries": { "Queries": [ "Get Services For Region" ] } } }
```

Comment: thank you, but it shows error:compiler.es5.js:12932 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'keys' could not be found ("
</ul> -->
{{robotTEst}}

Comment: the "keys" cannot find!!

Comment: this.http.get('../assets/data/robotTest.json').subscribe(data=> {
            this.robotTEst = data;
            this.myDataClass.getProjectName(data);
            this.projectName_robot = this.myDataClass.projectName;

        });

Comment: @LindaLi: Sorry pipe file code was missed. I have edited the code.